# Do I need to use Mutex with object instances?

Tags: java, concurrency, mutex

> Do I need to use Mutex with object
>   instances that may be concurrently
>   updating a different object instance?

Here is an example:

---

I have 5 Pen object instances, **50 Author threads**, and **3 Paper object instances**.

Any number of Authors may be using any number of Pens to write on any given paper.
I have created blocking queue to protect the Pen objects being accessed by Authors. 
However, the Pen instances need to take data from Author threads and append it to the (specified) Paper instance.

Question : Do I need to block the
write action of the Pen before
updating the Paper instance?

Comment: Could you post some code for your example? Also, is this homework?

Comment: @Thomas This is not a hypothetical question, so I don't have code. So, it is not a homework either :)

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, typo - I meant to say: This is a hypothetical question.

Comment: A plain lock/synchronized would be simpler/more efficient than using a blocking queue.

Comment: @PeterLawrey In that case would I construct the Authors as threads?

Comment: @Tom, how is that different to what you said in your post?

Comment: I am using blocking queue for pens - there is a pen repository/library that pops/puts the pen for each Author - effectively controlling which author gets which pen - and if all pens are in use, the author wait in FIFO order...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to synchronize the append action of the paper or block access otherwise, since you could have 5 Authors trying to concurrently write to one paper. So whenever a paper is being accessed by an Author you'd need to block it for the others.

If one Author can use multiple pens (of which I can't get the sense right now ;) ) you might also prevent multiple pens to write to the paper concurrently, so put a synchronized(pen) on the paper's write/append method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what I was expecting. However, multiple pens might be in action through multiple users. The write function is in the Pen object that takes the write content, Author id and Paper id. So, I guess whatever function call that Pen makes on the Paper object for the update should be updated? I see how synchronization would work on Paper object function :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why would your Pen objects have any state? It seems to me that Paper is the state holder. Pen for some reason is a limited resource ok, but I don't see why you need to have state in it.

If your Pen is stateless, or at least has immutable state, then there is no need for it to have any locks at all.

Comment: I am not sure where the question of Pen having a state comes in here. But the reason to use locks or a synchronized method is because potentially 5 threads of author may be using all 5 pen instances. In this case, if all 5 Pens are trying to write() on the paper, then this write() method needs to be synchronized. that is if i am not a complete fool ;)

Comment: @Tom if Pen has no state, then write() is the only thing that may need protection, depending on what state changes write makes and their ordering requirements. For instance, if you write a line of text, it may be that you only want a thread-safe container of lines.